# Is a left topological group which is a manifold a topological group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a left topological group, i.e. a topological space with group operation such that left multiplication $L_g : x \mapsto gx$ is continuous (but right multiplication and inversion are not required to be). Assume also $G$ to be a topological manifold. Does this imply that $G$ is a topological group?

EDIT 1: as pointed out by Yves Cornulier, the aswer is no if $G$ is not required to be connected. Hence, I would like to know if the statement still holds when $G$ is assumed to be connected.

EDIT 2: as discussed in the comments, we are also assuming $G$ to be paracompact, with countable atlas say.

Comment: If you start from a topological group $H$ with a closed subgroup $F$, define a topology on $H$ for which the left cosets $gF$ are open and have the original topology from $F$; thus $H_F$ is homeomorphic to the product of $F$ and a discrete set (in bijection with $G/F$). For this topology, the left translations of $H$ are still continuous. If $G=SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ and $H$ is a closed 1-parameter subgroup, still, the unit component is not normal and thus this fails to be a topological group.

Comment: If you make the coset of a a one-parameter subgroup open (and hence also closed), how can the group still be a topological manifold?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question since as I understand it, the answer is in my comment: the resulting topology on $H$ is homeomorphic to the product of $F$ with a discrete set; thus if $F$ is a topological manifold, so is $H_F$ (which is $H$ endowed with this topology, I forgot to say).

Comment: I see... thanks, if you write it as an answer I will accept it. In any case, I was not thinking about this kind of examples, I think I should add that $G$ is supposed to be connected.

Comment: Well, I sort of anticipated that you were primarily interested by the connected case, so I left the above as a comment.

Comment: (1) Does your definition of "manifold" include "paracompact" or something to make it metrizable?  So we should not work on a counterexample in the long line?

Comment: (2) Here is a nice theorem: if $G$ is a group and a complete metric space, and if multiplication is separately continuous, then it is a topological group (multiplication is jointly continuous and inversion is continuous).  So (in case your manifold is complete in some metric) it will be enough to show right multiplication is continuous.

Comment: yes, let's also assume $G$ paracompact, with countable atlas as topological manifold. @GeraldEdgar nice theorem, even if I don't see an immediate application to the present case, what is a reference for it?

Comment: @Gerald: every self-homeo of the long line(s) has a fixed point, so the long line will not provide any example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a counter-example with $G$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a discontinous additive homomorphism (constructed using a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$). Define a group operation $*$ on $\mathbb R^2$ by
$$
 (x,y)*(x',y') = (x+x'e^{f(y)},y+y') .
$$
This groups is a semidirect product of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ with respect to the action where $y\in\mathbb R$ acts on $\mathbb R$ by multiplication to $e^{f(y)}$. The formula is continuous in $(x',y')$ but not in $(x,y)$.

Comment: It is interesting to point out that the same example cannot work with compact semisimple Lie groups (replacing $xe^{f(y)}$ with the conjugacy $yxy^{-1}$, that sends as well $G\rightarrow{}Inn(G)\subseteq{}Aut(G)$), because in this case any automorphism is automatically continuous, as pointed out in http://mathoverflow.net/a/40700/3680

Comment: @Maurizio: what do you mean by "cannot work in compact semisimple Lie groups"? the conclusion would rather be that it cannot work with a semidirect product $H\rtimes K$ with $K$ compact semisimple. A further question would be whether there is an example with $G$ connected metrizable manifold, but not homeomorphic to any Lie group.

Comment: That the idea does not work "as is" with $H=K$, where I was looking for a non-continuous $H\rightarrow{}K$ that could then be composed with the canonical $K\rightarrow{}Inn(K)$. But actually I just realized that this can work very easily with $S^1$ and $SO(2)$, considering an isomorphical embedding $S^1\rightarrow{}SO(2)$ and a non-continuous homomorphism $S^1\rightarrow{}S^1$ (which exists). In this way we easily have a non-continuous homomorphism $S^1\rightarrow{}Aut(SO(2))$, and a similar example (that is also compact).