# Automorphisms of $G/Z(G)$ with $G$ simply connected

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-groups, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a simply connected (if necessary, compact Lie) group with finite center $Z$ and $p:G/\to G/Z$ be the canonical projection. Is there any way to know if every element in $\operatorname{Out}(G/Z)$ lifts to an element in $\operatorname{Out}(G)$?

I'm trying to understand who is $\operatorname{Out}(SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3)$.

Take $\varphi\in\operatorname{Out}(G/Z)$. From the fact that $G$ is simply connected we have that $p\circ \varphi$ lifts to a homomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}:G\to G$, but with kernel $Z$. Is there any way to turn this $\tilde{\varphi}$ into an automorphism?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40666/what-is-the-outer-automorphism-group-of-sun

Comment: Not true for the Heisenberg group. Is $Z$ finite? In that case $\tilde\phi$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Yes! Z is finite! I'm concerned about $Out(SU(3)/Z^3)$

Comment: @FriedrichKnop why is $\tilde{\varphi}$ an automorphism in this case?

Comment: Yes, if $G$ is a simply connected Lie group with discrete center $Z$, then both $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(G/Z)$ can be identified to $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$, and in both cases one gets Out by modding out by the canonical copy of $G/Z$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: Another perspective on what YCor said is that any automorphism of $G/Z$ lifts to $G$ simply because $G$ is the universal cover of $G/Z$, and the universal cover is functorial.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I will just answer the specific question the OP is interested in by giving a reference of sorts (in case it is helpful to the OP).

In Bourbaki *Éléments de mathématique: groupes et algèbres de Lie.* Chapitre 9 [Exercise 3](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Groupes_et_alg%C3%A8bres_de_Lie/m_bKwNLBZk4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22cyclique%20d%27ordre%202%22) one is asked to prove that $\mathrm{Out}(PSU(n))\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\geq 3$.

It seems to me that in this case one can show this explicitly.   The non-trivial non-inner automorphism is represented by the Cartan involution $A\mapsto (A^{-1})^T$ on $PSL(n,\mathbb{C})$ which simplifies to $A\mapsto \overline{A}$ on $PSU(n)$.