# Automorphism group of the special unitary group $SU(N)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-groups

Let us consider the automorphism group of the special unitary group $G=SU(N)$.

We know there is an exact sequence:
$$
0 \to \text{Inn}(G)  \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 0.
$$

For $G=SU(2)$, we have:

- $\text{Z}(SU(2)) =\mathbb Z_2$,
- $\text{Inn}(SU(2)) = SO(3)$,
- $\text{Out}(SU(2)) = 0$,

And so $\text{Aut}(SU(2))=SO(3)$.

For $N > 2$, we have:

- $\text{Z}(SU(N)) =\mathbb Z_{N}$,
- $\text{Inn}(SU(N)) = PSU(N)$,
- $\text{Out}(SU(N)) = \mathbb Z_2$.

My question is:

> Does $\text{Aut}(SU(N))=PSU(N) \times \mathbb Z_2$?
>   If not, does this answer depend on whether $N$ is odd or even?

It looks to me that there is a nontrivial fibration depending on something like $H^2(B\mathbb Z_2,PSU(N))$ due to $$ B\text{Inn}(G)  \to B\text{Aut}(G) \to B\text{Out}(G) \to B^2\text{Inn}(G)  \to$$ and
thus
$$ BPSU(N)  \to B\text{Aut}(G) \to B\mathbb Z_2 \to B^2PSU(N)  \to$$

But I do not know how to define $H^2(B\mathbb Z_2,PSU(N))$, if this is a correct thing to ponder.

Comment: this may be preliminary for answering your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40666/what-is-the-outer-automorphism-group-of-sun - which you may already know well.

Comment: In fact this completely answers the question.

Comment: what is the answer? I am asking the total Aut of $SU(N)$?

Comment: p.s. I am not asking Inn or Out of $SU(N)$.

Comment: The answer is that it is a semi-direct product $\operatorname{PSU} (N)\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$, with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acting on $\operatorname{PSU}(N) $ by conjugation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $G$ be a compact simple simply connected Lie group.  Then any automorphism of $G$ determines an automorphism of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and visa versa.  So $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is naturally isomorphic to the linear group $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.

The sequence $1\to \mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})\to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})\to \mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})\to 1$ is [split](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14735/12218).

Moreover, $\mathrm{Out}(G)\cong\mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})\cong \mathrm{Aut}(D_\mathfrak{g})$ where $D_\mathfrak{g}$ is the Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$.

The upshot is:

$$\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})\cong \mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})\rtimes \mathrm{Out}(G)\cong \mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})\rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(D_\mathfrak{g}).$$

For types $A_1, B_n, C_n, G_2, F_4, E_7, E_8$ there are no symmetries of the Dynkin diagram.  For $A_n$ ($n>1$), $D_n$ ($n\not=4$), and $E_6$, we have  $\mathrm{Aut}(D_\mathfrak{g})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  And in the final case of $D_4$, the symmetry group is the symmetric group on three letters.

In particular, as stated in the comments: $$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{SU}(n))\cong\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mathrm{PSU}(n)\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},&\text{ if } n\geq 3\\ \mathrm{PU}(2),&\text{ if }n=2. \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: PSU(2) = PU(2), yes?

Comment: Does it mean that the $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{PU}(n))=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{PSU}(n))=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{SU}(n))$, since they have the same Lie algebra:
$$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{PSU}(n))\cong\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mathrm{PSU}(n)\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},&\text{ if } n\geq 3\\ \mathrm{PU}(2),&\text{ if }n=2. \end{array}\right. ?$$

Comment: Do we have
$$\mathrm{Out}(G)\cong\mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})?$$
$$\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})?$$
$$\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})?$$
in general?

Comment: If these are true and I understand well, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: $PU(n)\cong PSU(n)$ in general.  For *simply-connected* Lie groups, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ and  $\mathrm{Out}(G)\cong \mathrm{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$.The same argument does not work for $\mathrm{Aut}(PG)$ since $PG$ is not generally simply-connected.  The inner automorphisms of the Lie algebra are the image of $G$ via the adjoint.  I think you need to generally figure out the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, Inn()≅Inn() also for simply-connected Lie groups?

Comment: I am not sure.  I think it is true for simple, simply-connected compact Lie groups.  "Proof:" Since $G$ is simple, the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})$ is $\mathfrak{g}$ itself.  Thus, since $G$ is simply-connected and compact, the abstract Lie group structure on $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})$ is a finite central quotient of $G$.  Since the center is in the kernel, it must be $PG$.  And $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong PG$ always. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks very much, what can we say about Inn, Out, and Aut(PSU(N)) then?
Is that true:
$$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{PSU}(n))\cong\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mathrm{PSU}(n) ,&\text{ if } n\geq 3\\ \mathrm{PSU}(2),&\text{ if }n=2. \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: also $$\mathrm{Out}(\mathrm{PSU}(n))\cong\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 ,&\text{ if } n\geq 3\\ 1,&\text{ if }n=2. \end{array}\right. ?$$

Comment: @annieheart I have answered your question and indulged your further queries in the comments.  If you have further questions you are welcome to make additional posts on MathOverFlow or on MathStackExchange.  The comments section is not the appropriate place for new questions.

Comment: answer accepted, thanks, I must not know enough about Out so I ask a new one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217455/automorphism-group-of-the-projective-unitary-group-pun

Comment: Do all real forms of a complex simple lie algebra have the same outer automorphism group as the complex simple lie algebra itself?