# Aut/Inn/Out Automorphism Groups of the unitary group $()$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, automorphism-groups

Given a group $G$, we denote the center Z$(G)$, we like to know the
automorphism group Aut($G$), the outer automorphism Out($G$) and the inner automorphism Inn($G$). They form short exact sequences:
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G \to \text{Inn}(G) \to 1, \quad \text{and    } \quad
1 \to \text{Inn}(G) \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1,
$$
and a combined exact sequence
$$
1 \to \text{Z}(G) \to G  \to \text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Out}(G) \to 1.
$$

### Question:

For $G=U(N)$ as a [unitary group, a subgroup in GL$(N, \mathbb{C})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) represented by rank-$N$ unitary matrices of complex coefficients $\mathbb{C}$.

We know the center $Z(U(N))=U(1)$.

What are the follows:

- Aut($U(N)$) = ?
- Inn($U(N)$)= ?
- Out($U(N)$)= ?

For $G=U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$ where $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is a finite abelian group of order $k$, which requires $k \vert N$ to be factorized.

We know the center $Z(U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k)=U(1)$.

- Aut($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$) = ?
- Inn($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$)= ?
- Out($U(N)/\mathbb{Z}_k$)= ?

### Additional background info (warm-up, which I had obtained):

If $G$ is a simply-connected compact Lie group and ${\bf{g}}$ is its Lie algebra (which would necessarily be semi-simple),
then $\text{Inn}(G)=\text{Inn}({\bf g})=\mathrm{P}G$,
$\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Aut}({\bf g})$,
and
$ \text{Out}(G)=\text{Out}({\bf g})= \text{Aut}(D_{{\bf{g}} })$ is isomorphic to the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram $D_{{\bf{g}} }$ of the Lie algebra ${\bf{g}} $.

- For $G=U(1)$, we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =U(1)$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = 1$,
  $\text{Aut}(G)=\text{Out}(G) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
- For $G=SU(2)$,
  we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =\mathbb{Z}_2$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = SO(3)$,
  $\text{Aut}(G)=PSU(2)=SO(3)$, and
  $\text{Out}(G) = 1$.
- For $G=SU(N)$ with $N$ $\geq 3$,
  we have
  $\text{Z}(G) =\mathbb{Z}_{N}$,
  $\text{Inn}(G) = PSU(N)$,
  and
  $\text{Out}(G) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
  We also have $\text{Aut}(G)=PSU(N) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

p.s. An earlier version of a [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4028575/79069) has not reached a conclusion.

Comment: In your example $G$ is not just a group but a topological group. Are you asking about continuous automorphisms or arbitrary automorphisms?

Comment: () is certainly a unitary Lie group.

Comment: Do you mean (()/ℤ) may be something else than Lie group? (It is Lie group I thought) thanks for comments

Comment: you may also want to compare with these examples https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4104993/79069

Comment: @wonderich: You have not answered YCor's question. Perhaps comments have been deleted -- at present this comment chain makes no sense.

Comment: The lines at the beginning of your post suggest you're considering abstract groups, hence with the group of all their group automorphisms. While it is standard for a Lie group to consider the group of its automorphisms as topological group (i.e., which are continuous with continuous inverse)— these include inner automorphisms, but not all automorphisms in general. This why I'm asking to clarify your question.

Comment: A answer to your question is in Freundenthal Linear Lie groups, Academic press. Also in Lecture of Lie groups by Adams. Some of the books written by Helgason, have a complete answer too.

Comment: Hi guys, I am not sure the discussions about the group v.s. abstract group v.s. topological group -- I think wonderich may mean similar things like this https://mathoverflow.net/a/330676/106497